# Irreducibility of polynomials $x^{2^{n}}+1$

Tags: polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I would like to if the polynomials of the form $x^{2^{n}}+1$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and in that case if there is some "easy" proof for that (where easy means not using a big theory like Galois).

Comment: Rational Root Test?

Comment: @JessePFrancis That wouldn't show irreducibility, only that it doesn't have any linear factors.  For example, $(x^2+1)^2$ doesn't have any rational roots, but that doesn't mean it's irreducible.

Comment: @Hayden, but in this particular case involving only two terms?

Comment: @JessePFrancis I don't know which particular case you're referring to, the OP's polynomial or my example.  You can use Rational Root Theorem to show a polynomial is irreducible when the degree is 2 or 3, but for any higher degree you would need to do more than just that.  If in the OP's example, $n=1$, then yes, Rational Root Theorem shows irreducibility, but in mine it doesn't (hence me giving the example).

Comment: @Hayden, thank you. I meant OP's polynomial! Anyway, I feel its inappropriate to discuss it here, hence asked a [new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310567/cases-where-irreducibility-of-polynomials-over-mathbb-f-iff-it-has-no-roots)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{2^n}+1$. Note that if $f(x+1)$ is irreducible, then so is $f(x)$.

We have:

$$f(x+1)=\left(x^{2^n} + \binom{2^n}{1}x^{2^n-1}+\dots+\binom{2^n}{2^n-1}x+1\right)+1$$

Note that $2$ divides all the coefficients except that of $x^{2^n}$, and $4$ does not divide the constant coefficient, $2$. Thus the polynomial is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion.